# Convert Hex String to Binary String - Java

Tags: java, string, binary, hex

Ok so i want to convert a Hex string to a Binary String so that i can do some bit swaps and subs etc down the line and i come across what i thought was the answer on here [Convert hex string to binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640803/convert-hex-string-to-binary-string) but this caused me some problems.

```
String hexToBinary(String hexadecimalString) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(hexadecimalString, 16);
    String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    return binaryString;
}
```

However, for example if i passed in the hexadecimal string "03" it would only return a binary string of "11". Or if i were to pass in the hex string "41" it would return a binary string of "1000001". 
How can I make it so that it will always return a binary string of length 8 bits?
All help greatly appreciated in advance :)

Tried your suggestion of padding the binary string but it didn't work, this is what i tried, can you see what I've done wrong?

```
String hexToBinary(String hexString) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
    String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    String padded = String.format("%8s", binaryString.replace(' ', '0'));
    return padded;
}
```

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246326/convert-hexadecimal-string-hex-to-a-binary-string

Comment: You just need to left-pad with zeroes until your string is 8 characters long

Comment: The `replace()` must be called on the result of `String.format()` not on the `binrayString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Try this:

```
String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0')
```

Comment: Hi Iswanto, i tried your suggestion but it still returns the same string with no padding?

Comment: @lifeisaloop Then you must have done something wrong. As the example is right. For 41 it returns `00101001`.

Comment: Yes had a look again there and i had mistyped it. Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
String hexToBinary(String hexadecimalString) {
int i = Integer.parseInt(hexadecimalString, 16);
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
while (binaryString .length() < 8) {
        binaryString  = "0" + binaryString ;
    }
return binaryString;
}
```

adding 0 at start of string till length of binaryString is 8

Answer (score 0):

Out of many other solutions this could be one.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(41);
for (int i = binaryString.length(); i < 8; i++) {
    sb.append('0');
}
sb.append(binaryString);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

or this one

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("00000000");
sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(41));
System.out.println(sb.substring(sb.length()-8));
```

or even this one

```
String s = "00000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(41);
System.out.println(s.substring(s.length()-8));
```